# Convert characters of the string in alphabet integer position?

Tags: c#, char, int, character, letter

I want to calculate the character integer position of the string.
But when I run this method it calculates only the first char.

I must have output like this:

A = 1 + D = 4 + E = 5,  => 10

```
private int letterNumber(string letter)
{
    char c = letter[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < letter.Length; i++)
    {
        c = (char)letter[i];
        return char.ToUpper(c) - 64;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Your return statement is in your loop, hence why it cancels after the first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return inside the loop - which is not your desired behaviour. With some minor refactoring, we can clean this up a bit:

```
private int letterNumber(string letter)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < letter.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = letter[i]; // declare it in loop - you overwrite it here anyway
        sum += char.ToUpper(c) - 64;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this

```
return char.ToUpper(c) - 64;
```

it exits the method and returns the first value, try storing the results in a variable and the returning it, like this

```
private int letterNumber(string letter)
{
    int sum = 0;
    char c = letter[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < letter.Length; i++)
    {
        c = (char)letter[i];
        sum += char.ToUpper(c) - 64;

    }

    return sum;
 }
```

Also, A = 1 + D = 4 + E = 4, => 9 :)